# Getting an unexpected result while configuring Swagger with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm pretty much new to Swagger and I started Documenting very simple my web service that I've build using Spring Boot.

The problem is, After I configure swagger, in the browser when I type **localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html** I get this following screen with some weird popup message that says "Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway". 
I do know it may seems repeated question, but I couldn't resolve this at all with all those answers given. Following, I've posted the screenshot and complete code where I didn't what went wrong. Please make me understand If I went wrong.

Screen shot:[image]

**Code**
SwaggerConfig.java

```
package com.test.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .paths(regex("/greet.*"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

TestApplication.java

```
package com.test.config;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.test.controllers") 
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

TestController.java

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greet")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping
        public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello There";
    }
}
```

In the above code both **SwaggerConfig.java** and **TestApplication.java** belongs to same package i.e **com.test.config** and **TestController.java** belongs to **com.test.controllers**

This is all the code I've and in the pom.xml I've two following dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It works for me. Sometimes these things pop up when you turn on some browser extensions. Try with incognito window or some other browser

Comment: In some browsers like Mozilla, There is no alert screen getting displayed, but still Documentation isn't appearing at all. In the TestController, for the getGreeting() method, A documentation should be visible right?

Comment: @Barath Are you sure, you are able to see the docs?

Comment: yes I was able to see the swagger docs with your configuration. I faced similar issue earlier, it is due to browser, try clearing your cache.

Comment: double check your @ComponentScan it looks like your SwaggerConfig doesnt get scanned at all. Add a sysout and check it out. Because com.test.controllers is getting scanned and com.test.config is under different  pkg.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it adding the annotation `@EnableSwagger2` on Application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2 //this
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks! it works. i had same issue when deploy to AWS EC2

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue when deploying the Spring-boot application as a war artifact. While running the application with the embedded tomcat(as an standalone spring-boot app) it was working fine where as while deploying the war file to remote tomcat facing the above issue.

On bit of dig around, I found that I was missing the Servlet Initializer for my application for the war archive.

Following worked for me like a charm.

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application){ 
   return application.sources(TestApplication.class); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if Swagger is behind any auth, you need to do following in SpringBoot Security

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**").permitAll().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
```

Then you access [Swagger UI Documentation](http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html)

Answer (score 1):

just add these three URLs in your configure method of ResourceServerConfiguration class "/swagger-ui" , "/swagger-ui.html" and "/swagger-resources/**". it can resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, try changing .paths to .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("package where your controller is com.demo.example.controller")).build(); give this a shot and if it doesn't work please let me know.

Comment: No. Just In browser, I'm not able to view the documentation. To this url "http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html", It's just displaying the popup as it exactly showing in the screen shot that I've specified in the question.

Comment: sorry, so you are trying to access the documentation through localhost:8080/greet/swagger-ui.html or just localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html?

Comment: try accessing the greet one, i think that should be the actual path of your service

Answer (score 0):

In my case this bean configuration was a problem maker.

```
@Bean
public CsvMapper csvSerializerMapper() {
    stuff()
}
```

Spring used it to initialize jackson objectMapper for Spring, which was failing silently.
Fixed it by adding bean with object mapper.

```
@Autowired
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    return builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
}
```