# Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway

Tags: spring, swagger, microservices, api-gateway

I already went [Why does springfox-swagger2 UI tell me "Unable to infer base url."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47425048/why-does-springfox-swagger2-ui-tell-me-unable-to-infer-base-url?rq=1) and [Getting an unexpected result while configuring Swagger with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520149/getting-an-unexpected-result-while-configuring-swagger-with-spring-boot) and not using Spring Security at all and for each service, I am using `@EnableSwagger2` annotations.

I'm following tutorial from link: https://dzone.com/articles/quick-guide-to-microservices-with-spring-boot-20-e and using `gateway-service` for the project to run instead of `proxy-service`.

[image]

**gateway-service.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8060

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8061/eureka/

logging:
  pattern: 
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} %m%n"

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
      - id: employee-service
        uri: lb://employee-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/employee/**
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/employee/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
      - id: department-service
        uri: lb://department-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/department/**
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/department/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
      - id: organization-service
        uri: lb://organization-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/organization/**
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/organization/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
```

OrganizationApplication.java and all other services are implemented exactly like this.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableSwagger2
public class OrganizationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrganizationApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("pl.piomin.services.organization.controller"))
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder().version("1.0").title("Organization API").description("Documentation Organization API v1.0").build());
    }

    @Bean
    OrganizationRepository repository() {
        OrganizationRepository repository = new OrganizationRepository();
        repository.add(new Organization("Microsoft", "Redmond, Washington, USA"));
        repository.add(new Organization("Oracle", "Redwood City, California, USA"));    
        return repository;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui dependencies to 2.9.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have below 3 dependency in your pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>{your.spring.fox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>{your.spring.fox.version}</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>{your.spring.fox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

NB: springfox version should be same on the above 3 dependencies otherwise you might get other errors

Import the [SpringDataRestConfiguration](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/current/springfox/documentation/spring/data/rest/configuration/SpringDataRestConfiguration.html) class to your **OrganizationApplication** class as shown below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)
public class OrganizationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrganizationApplication.class, args);
    }

     // you other code to go here
     -----
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I get this error was when I added wrapping aspect for DTOs and it goes out when I add skipping of wrapping for not my DTOs, for example `springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration`:

```
package ru.nashev.try2.controller;

import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyAdvice;
import ru.nashev.try2.dto.ResultDataDTO;
import ru.nashev.try2.dto.ResultErrorDTO;
import ru.nashev.try2.dto.ResultSuccessDTO;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class ResponseBodyHandler implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter methodParameter, MediaType mediaType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass, ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        if (body == null) {
            return new ResultDataDTO(new ResultSuccessDTO());
        } else if (!body.getClass().getName().startsWith("ru.nashev.try2.dto")) { // skip swagger classes etc
            return body;
        } else if (body instanceof ResultErrorDTO) {
            return body;
        } else {
            return new ResultDataDTO(body);
        }
    }
}
```